# JavaScript is function static

Tags: javascript, static

Is it possible to determine whether a JavaScript function is static? I've written a class to test this but I need to code the `isStatic` method which should return a boolean showing whether the func passed in is static (return true) or not (return false). Anyone got code for this? thx

```js
class MyClass {
  static myStaticMethod() {
    return 'hi'
  }
  myMethod() {
    return 'hi'
  }
  isStatic(func) {
    // return a boolean here which shows whether func is static or not
  }
  test1() {
    return this.isStatic(MyClass.myStaticMethod)
  }
  test2() {
    return this.isStatic(this.myMethod)
  }
}

const obj = new MyClass()
console.log(obj.test1()) // should return true - currently returns undefined
console.log(obj.test2()) // should return false - currently returns undefined
```

Comment: Why do you need to determine this at run time?

Comment: I am using a JavaScript decorator. The decorated function must be pure. Since it is not possible to easily determine if a function is pure my thinking is to enforce that the decorated function is static. This is because static functions are mostly always pure (unless you stick a Math.random statement in them). This is intended to protect developers against themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions don't "know" this about themselves. When you pass a function reference, it's just that a function reference — it doesn't keep track of who holds a reference to it. There's nothing special about the function itself that makes it a static function.

This is probably fragile and there are likely edge cases especially when you want to extend the class. With that said, you could search through the class's prototype and see if one  of it's properties holds a reference to the function in question:

```js
class MyClass {
  static myStaticMethod() {
    return 'hi'
  }
  myMethod() {
    return 'hi'
  }
  isStatic(func) {
    // return a boolean here which shows whether func is static or not
    for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyClass)) {
      if (func === MyClass[name])
        return true
    }
    return false
  }
  test1() {
    return this.isStatic(MyClass.myStaticMethod)
  }
  test2() {
    return this.isStatic(this.myMethod)
  }
}

const obj = new MyClass()
console.log(obj.test1()) // should return true - currently returns undefined
console.log(obj.test2()) // should return false - currently returns undefined
```

It might make more sense for `isStatic` to be a static function itself. Then you could avoid hard-coding the class name into the method:

```js
class MyClass {
  static myStaticMethod() {
    return 'hi'
  }
  myMethod() {
    return 'hi'
  }
  static isStatic(func) {
    // return a boolean here which shows whether func is static or not
    for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)){
      if (func === this[name]) 
        return true
    }
    return false
  }
  test1() {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.isStatic(MyClass.myStaticMethod)
  }
  test2() {
    return  Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.isStatic(this.myMethod)
  }
}

const obj = new MyClass()
console.log(obj.test1()) // should return true - currently returns undefined
console.log(obj.test2()) // should return false - currently returns undefined
```